# visio 2016 crow's feet notation confusion

Tags: database-design, visio

I have the following diagram:

[image]

How do I expand the entity to add more rows so I can put another entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the extra fields are "dragged" over from the menu manually or can be copy/pasted in from the current lowest row.